# 404 not found while a php curl request on aspx page

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I'm trying to login into an .aspx page with a PHP curl. At now I am grabbing the login page to get the VIEWSTATE and compose the correct url to make the request, after that there is an other curl request that post fields and log in. This curl call returns a 404 error. I've already tryied to make an other curl request with an other curl but it redirects to the login page.
Where am I wrong??

```
    include('../dom/simple_html_dom.php');
    $ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE"); 
    $url = 'http://www.EXAMPLE.com/Shop/Login.aspx';

//FIRST CALL TO GRAB THE VIEWSTATE VALUE
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // Accepts all CAs 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); //Uses cookies from the temp file 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Tells cURL to follow redirects 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $html = str_get_html($output);

//GRABBING THE VALUES
    $evttarget  = 'LogonBox%24btnLogin';
    $evtarg     = '';
    $viewstate  = urlencode($html->find('input#__VIEWSTATE')[0]->value);
    $viewgen    = urlencode($html->find('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')[0]->value);
    $username   = 'MYUSERNAME';
    $password   = 'MYPASSWORD';

//COMPOSING THE URL 
    $url = 'http://www.EXAMPLE.com/Shop/Login.aspx?__EVENTTARGET='.$evttarget.'&__EVENTARGUMENT='.$evtarg.'&__VIEWSTATE='.$viewstate.'&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR='.$viewgen.'&LogonBox%24txtUsername='.$username.'&LogonBox%24txtPassword='.$password;

//LOGIN REQUEST
    $ch = curl_init();
    print $url;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); // Accepts all CAs 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); //Uses cookies from the temp file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Tells cURL to follow redirects 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

THIS RETURNS A 404 ERROR
```

Comment: I have tried to compose the url and paste it in the browser's address bar and it returns the 404 error too, so I suppose that the problem could concern the header, am I right?